# get last month and year using carbon laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

This might be a simple, I've `$month` and `$year`, but I'm trying to get `lastMonthYear` and `lastToLastMonthYear`.

```
    $date = Carbon::create($year, $month)->startOfMonth();

    $sameMonthLastYear = $date->subYear()->format('Ym');
    $lastMonthYear =  $date->subMonth()->format('Ym');
    $LastToLastMonthYear = $date->subMonth()->format('Ym');
```

Considering $month=9 and $year=2021, I'm trying to get

```
sameMonthLastYear = 202009
lastMonthYear = 202108
lastToLastMonthYear = 202107
```

but I'm getting

```
sameMonthLastYear = 202009
lastMonthYear = 202008
lastToLastMonthYear = 202008
```

Because $date value is keep updating for every line. Is there any way to get the expected result?

Comment: Please select one of the answers below as "The answer" if it suits your question to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `copy()` method:

```
$date = Carbon::create($year, $month)->startOfMonth();

$sameMonthLastYear = $date->copy()->subYear()->format('Ym');
$lastMonthYear =  $date->copy()->subMonth()->format('Ym');
$LastToLastMonthYear = $date->copy()->subMonths(2)->format('Ym');
```

Answer (score 4):

The right way is to use `CarbonImmutable`:

```php
$date = CarbonImmutable::create($year, $month);

$sameMonthLastYear = $date->subYear()->format('Ym'); //202009
$lastMonthYear =  $date->subMonth()->format('Ym'); //202108
$LastToLastMonthYear = $date->subMonths(2)->format('Ym'); //202107
```

With `CarbonImmutable`, the changes you make to `$date` are not persisted.

I also removed the `startOfMonth` method, it was useless since by default, the Carbon instance will be:

```
Carbon\CarbonImmutable @1630454400 {#5430
    date: 2021-09-01 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00),
}
```

Comment: I recommend `CarbonImmutable::create($year, $month, 1)` to avoid unexpected overflow (when subtracting month from 31st for instance)

Comment: @KyleK `CarbonImmutable::create($year, $month)` has its third argument (day) to `1` by default (that's why the `date` property is `2021-09-01 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)`). This is the function declaration: `public static function create($year = 0, $month = 1, $day = 1, $hour = 0, $minute = 0, $second = 0, $tz = null)`

Comment: Oups, correct, I messed it with `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m', '2021-09')`